# Can't perform react state in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm having a problem. been browsing some questions here but seems doesn't work for me.

I'm getting this error in my three pages when I'm using the useEffect.

[image: Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component]

This is the code of my useEffect

```
const UserDetailsPage = () => {


  const classes = useStyles()

  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
    _id: "",
    name: "",
    phone: "",
    address: "",
    birthdate: "",
    gender: "",
    messenger: "",
    photo: "",
    email: "",
  })
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)
  const { height, width } = useWindowDimensions()

  const {
    _id,
    name,
    phone,
    address,
    photo,
    gender,
    messenger,
    birthdate,
    email,
  } = userData

  useEffect(() => {
    const user = getUser()

    getUserById("/user/" + user.userId, user.token)
      .then((data) => {
        setUserData(data)
        setLoaded(true)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short of `getUserById` returning a cancel token to cancel any inflight network requests, or an "unsubscribe" method, you can use a React ref to track if the component is still mounted or not, and not enqueue the state update if the component has already unmounted.

```
const isMountedRef = React.useRef(false);

useEffect(() => {
  isMountedRef.current = true;
  return () => isMountedRef.current = false;
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  const user = getUser();

  getUserById("/user/" + user.userId, user.token)
    .then((data) => {
      if (isMountedRef.current) {
        setUserData(data);
        setLoaded(true);
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}, []);
```

Comment: I prefer this solution over mine as the `isMountedRef` can be reused in the component if there are multiple API calls inside different `useEffects`.

Comment: @Moistbobo It's also independent of the "componentDidUpdate" lifecycle of other `useEffect` hooks with dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the async call in `useEffect` finishing and then attempting to `setState` after the page is no longer in focus.

It can be avoided by refactoring the `useEffect` like so:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    // created a boolean to check if the component is mounted, name is arbitrary
    let mounted = true;

    const user = getUser();

    getUserById("/user/" + user.userId, user.token)
      .then((data) => {
        // only setState if mounted === true
        if (mounted) {
          setUserData(data);
          setLoaded(true);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

    // set mounted to false on cleanup
    return () => {
      mounted = false;
    };
  }, []);
```

What's different here is that I use a `mounted` boolean to check if the page is currently mounted. By wrapping the `setState` call inside an if state, I can check if it's safe to `setState`, therefore avoiding the error.

[Additional reading](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1146879067591008270)

Answer (score 1):

This happens when your component is unmounting before setting your state. Try this code below to check if the component is mounted or not.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let isMounted = true;   // add a flag to check component is mounted

  getUserById("/user/" + user.userId, user.token)
  .then((data) => {
    if(mounted) {  // set state only when component is mounted
       setUserData(data)
       setLoaded(true)
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })

  return () => { isMounted = false }; // cleanup toggles value, if unmounted
}, []);
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use async tasks in useEffect. Define an async function and call in your useEffect.

Example:

```
const getSTH = async() =>{
    getUserById("/user/" + user.userId, user.token)
     .then((data) => {
        if(mounted) {  // set state only when component is mounted
        setUserData(data)
        setLoaded(true)
     }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
       console.log(error)
    })

}

useEffect (()=>{
    getSTH();
},[])
```

I think this approach will help you.